# Multi column IN Sql using Spring

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate, multiple-columns

Using Spring's DAO capabilities, how can I pass a list of multi column parameters to a query? i.e. I want to execute a query which is similar to the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE
(COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) IN
( (VAL_1, VAL2), (VAL_3, VAL_4))
```

Does NamedParameterJdbcTemplate have support for such a query?

i.e. My query will look like  SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 
    WHERE
    (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) IN (:val1, :val2)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just combine the two criteria with an **AND**:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE COLUMN_1 IN (VAL_1, VAL2) AND COLUMN2 IN (VAL_3, VAL_4)
```

Comment: Wont this retrieve invalid combinations ; i.e. Column 1 = Val 2 and Column 2 = Val 3 ? I need to maintain the combinations

Comment: AH - I see. Then you would want 

SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (COLUMN_1 IN (VAL_1) AND COLUMN2 IN (VAL_3) ) OR (COLUMN_1 IN (VAL_2) AND COLUMN2 IN (VAL_4))